# How to pass parameter to root path (home route) in go_router?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I'm using [`go_router_builder`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router_builder) to build routes. Here's one:

```dart
@TypedGoRoute<HomeRoute>(
  path: '/',
)
class HomeRoute extends GoRouteData {
  final Foo? $extra;
  HomeRoute([this.$extra]);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return HomeScreen();
  }
}
```

Now the problem is I can't figure out a way to pass the `Foo` object to `HomeRoute` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your object if you write like below code.

```dart
void _tap() => HomeRoute(Foo(id: 1)).go(context);
```

https://docs.page/csells/go_router/typed-routing#extra-parameter